# How to add Immovable feature in Project Job Scheduling solution?

Tags: optaplanner

I need to add immovable feature to my project job scheduling solution, I have add locked property at Allocation class like this :

```
private boolean locked = false;
```

update the NotSourceOrSinkAllocationFilter class to include locked checking like this :

```
JobType jobType = allocation.getJob().getJobType();
return !allocation.isLocked() && jobType != JobType.SOURCE && jobType != JobType.SINK;
```

I tried to run it first, when the result appears, I immediately terminate the solving earlier. Then move one single allocation and set it to locked. When I run it again, it will gave me a infeasible solution. 
Here is my screenshot:

initializes schedule:
[image: Initialized Solution]
adhoc decision:
[image: Target Solution]
try to moved it, lock it, and solve it again
[image: moved]
unexpected result come out (it just come back to the previous allocation)
[image: result]

Please help me to add this immovable feature. Thanks.

Comment: Did you annotate that filter on the planning, something like: `@PlanningEntity(...       movableEntitySelectionFilter = NotSourceOrSinkAllocationFilter.class)`?

Comment: Are you using a `chained=true` planning variable? There's a [known issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-239) with chained vs immovable.

Comment: Yes, I have already annotate that filter on the planning entity class (it's already annotate from your example solution). Where should I check this "chained=true" thing?

Comment: When I think about it again, yes, project job scheduling using chained planning entities, because one of the hard constraint was the job precendence, which mean a job must only start when all the predecessor jobs finished. So how do we deal with this situation now?

Comment: See the workaround in the linked jira. It's clumsily and there are some pitfalls, but I know users who got it working correctly.

Comment: From jira: Workaround: add custom move filters which if the the getNextEntity isn't immovable for change and swap moves. As for subchain moves... don't allow reversing. As for 2opt moves, don't allow intra moves (because they reverse).
In any case, the workaround is clumsy and this issue is important. | But I still don't get it, could you please explain it more detail about the workaround? Thanks