# Immovable planning entities for chained entities

Tags: java, optaplanner, drools-planner

I was trying to implement immovable planning entities for my chained entities. My planning problem was similar to project job scheduling example from optaplanner examples. Previously I have post a question about a problem to lock my chained entities in here: [How to add Immovable feature in Project Job Scheduling solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27601045/how-to-add-immovable-feature-in-project-job-scheduling-solution/27736351#27736351)
The project lead have already giving me some workaround from jira: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-239. Now I was trying to write the code for the workaround, but get stuck. Please somebody help me to complete these workaround code.

From jira:

> Workaround: add custom move filters which if the getNextEntity
>   isn't immovable for change and swap moves. As for subchain moves...
>   don't allow reversing. As for 2opt moves, don't allow intra moves
>   (because they reverse). In any case, the workaround is clumsy and this
>   issue is important.

I just trying to understand the workaround, so here it is, please someone help me to complete this workaround :

The custom move filters which if the getNextEntity isn't immovable for change and swap moves :

```
public boolean accept(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Allocation allocation) {         
   JobType jobType = allocation.getJob.getJobType();
   boolean isLocked = false;
   for(Allocation nextAllocation : allocation.getSuccessorAllocationList()) {
      isLocked = nextAllocation.isLocked();
   }       
   return !isLocked && jobType != JobType.SOURCE && jobType != JobType.SINK;
}
```

The next sentence was not clearly, so I don't understand what to do with it :

> As for 2opt moves, don't allow intra moves (because they reverse).

I would really appreciate if anyone want to help me complete this code, thanks.

Comment: Dear the.wizard,

I have the same probem as you. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28047115/immovable-customer-appointment-time-windows-for-vehicle-routing

Where (in which file) did you add the code above? What is meant by 2opt moves?

Regards,
Milenko

Comment: 2opt moves is new on master (not yet released) and they'll probably name TailChainSwapMove instead, because that's more self-explanatory (2opt is the academic term)

Comment: PLANNER-239 is on my todo list... (as are a bunch of other work)

Comment: Does this means right now my problem didn't have solution and I should wait until you release the TailChainSwapMove? Is there any workaround for this problem without need to waiting for the release?

Comment: Dear Geoffrey,
your comment: Workaround: add custom move filters which if the getNextEntity isn't immovable for change and swap moves. As for subchain moves... don't allow reversing. As for 2opt moves, don't allow intra moves (because they reverse). In any case, the workaround is clumsy and this issue is important." 

Can you give an example how this should be done? 

I have a problem that if I start with a completely unsolved case that than in the SelectionFIlter "return false" works. In the case of a partly solved solutution also with unassigned cutomers to vehicles it crashs.

Thanks a lot.