# Immovable customer appointment time windows for vehicle routing

Tags: optaplanner

I read the following question and the proposed solution:

[Immovable planning entities for chained entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972035/immovable-planning-entities-for-chained-entities)

In our problem we would like to send a set of technicians and customer with their appointment windows to optaplanner with the following condition:

Some customers were already served or are being served, so all of them are already belonging to a certain technician who did (is doing) the work there. 
It is similar to the following example: 
I start the time dependent vehicle routing example and stop it far before the "best" solution is obtained. 
Then I want to use this solution as input, whereby from each technician in the simplest case only the very first customer of the chain has to be set immovable (because he was already served), but all the others are still available for the rest optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 6.2 reference manual, take a look at:

- **immovable planning entities**: don't change the entities which are already assigned (= by locking them)
- **non-volatile replanning**: prefer not to change the entities which are already assigned, unless the gain is worth it

Comment: Ah, I forgot that due to issue with immovable and VRP, immovably only works there if an immovable entity has no non-immovable entities in the chain in front of it.